# CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY clBuildProgram

Tags: java, memory, opencl, lwjgl

I have this code (Java / LWJGL) to create my OpenCL program.

```
try 
{
    CL.create();
} catch (LWJGLException e1)
{
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
platform = CLPlatform.getPlatforms().get(0);
devices = platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU);
try 
{
    context = CLContext.create(platform, devices, null, null, null);
} catch (LWJGLException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, devices.get(0), CL_QUEUE_PROFILING_ENABLE, null);

program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, source, null);
checkCLError(clBuildProgram(program, devices.get(0), "", null));

kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "main", null);
```

It works and throws no errors with this OpenCL kernel:

```
kernel void main(
                global const float *hitboxes,
                global const float *positions,
                global const float *rotations,
                global const float *velocities,
                global const float *colliders,
                global const float *weights,
                global float *answerPos,
                global float *answerRot,
                global float *answerVel
                )
{
    int id = get_global_id(0);
}
```

But if I add ANY code to the main method or other methods / structs it throws "CL_OUT_OF_HOST_MEMORY" in `clBuildProgram` method. Can someone tell me why? I have another OpenCL program (also LWJGL), that is basically the same. Except it works.

Comment: code formatted, typo fixed

Comment: Can you also show how do you pass data to the device?

Comment: Does clBuildProgram return any error message in build log?

Comment: Could you rename your kernel to something different than "main" and try again?

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into a similar issue.
Mine was pretty silly though – I forgot to add `__kernel` prefix to the main function prototype so the program had no entry point.